# Callback in onClick()

Tags: java, android, callback

Please I would like to understand something that is happening to me.

I kindly ask if somebody would be so kind to explain to me.

Thanks

---

THE ONCLICK

I have an **OnClickListener** which contains **2 callbacks**:

`onRequestFailure`
`onRequestSuccess`

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
spicemanager.execute( new RequestListener<Alltips>() {
    @Override
    public void onRequestFailure(SpiceException spiceException) {
        //Do soume stuff
            }

    @Override
    public void onRequestSuccess(final Alltips alltips) {
    //Do some other stuff
            }
            });
}
```

---

WHAT HAPPENS

When I click the first time everything goes fine,

**if I click for more times the `onClick` stops responding.**

---

WHY IS THAT HAPPENING?

I suppose that if `onClick` never returns that could be the cause,

but this is not the situation (I think), I think `onClick` returns even if the callbacks are not called...

Please can somebody explain it to me?

---

HOW TO AVOID

how do I avoid such a situation?

Comment: Could you give us more info please? Like, on what is your click listener added, are you sure you don't set it to null? Did you tried to put a breakpoint at this line: "spicemanager.execute( new RequestListener<Alltips>() " ? :)

Comment: @Cata Hi Cata, yes I am sure the listener is set to a non null View (indeed it executes at least once). No I did not try to debug it actually...

Comment: Can you add a breakpoint there please and see if the onClick is actually the issue or not? :)

Comment: You need to show more code.  What is spicemanager, an AsyncTask?  If so, the callback will rarely to never be called before onClick finishes.  Really how would we know why a callback in an unknown class is or isn't called?

Comment: @GabeSechan Hi Gabe, my guess indeed is that the callback do not get called "back" before `onClick()` finishes. The problem is not if the callbacks are called or not but why `onClick()` stops working :-)

Comment: @Cata I am trying now :-)

Comment: @LisaAnne And we can't know without a lot more code.  Whaat is spicemanager and what is it doing?  If it is an AsyncTask-  are you just waiting for the background process to finish? Remember that multiple AsyncTasks are queued and run on 1 thread so if there were pending tasks you may be waiting for them to finish.  The best thing for you to do is put breakpoints in your spicemanager, callbacks, and onClick and see which are called or not called

Comment: @GabeSechan Hi Gabe thanks, but the point is not if the callbacks are called or not, but what happens to the `onClick` method in particular if the callbacks are not called before `onClick` finishes...

Comment: @Cata Cata in debugging seems to work OK, I guess that is because the we are in debug where everything is slow... I guess...

Comment: @LisaAnne Nothing happens.  It returns when execute finishes, no matter whether callbacks are called or not.  It doesn't even know the callbacks exist.  I think you're very confused over how callbacks work.

Comment: Then please print a message before that line in onClick and see that it prints.. I think that your issue is actually the spicemanager which will not run again for some reason.. try to create a new instance of spicemanager in onClick each time..

Comment: @GabeSechan mmm OK but what happens then when the callbacks get called? Do the code `Do soume stuff` or `Do some other stuff` get executed? Yes I would say

Comment: Yes, but depending on the implementation of spicemanager.  One of them may be called, or both, or neither.  Or if its asynchronous the call may happen 3 hours from now.  There's not enough code to know.